# Image first spatial derivative, SciPy Ndimage filters convolution faster than array slicing?

Tags: numpy, scipy, convolution, calculus, dft

For an image, I have implemented the first spatial derivative (along an arbitrary dimension) using central finite differences in two ways: (1) using `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve` with a central finite differences kernel and (2) using array slicing to compute the differences.

I thought for sure that (2) would be faster in general, and it is for 2D images, but for large 3D images, (1) is definitely faster. I can't believe the DFT + multiplication is faster than just a bunch of subtractions. Can anyone explain this?

code for (1):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.filters as ndif
_MASK = np.array([1.0, 0.0, -1.0])
def partial(img, vox, axis, mode='wrap'):
    """Return partial derivative of *img* w.r.t. *axis* direction"""
    d = len(img.shape)
    shm = np.identity(d)*2 + 1
    m = np.reshape(_MASK, shm[axis])/(2.0*vox[axis])
    return ndif.convolve(img, m, mode=mode)
```

code for (2):

```
import numpy as np
so0 = slice(None, None, None)
so1 = slice(None, -2, None)
so2 = slice(2, None, None)
def partial(img, vox, axis, mode='wrap'):
    """Return partial derivative of *img* w.r.t. *axis* direction"""
    d = len(img.shape)
    soa = [so0]*d
    soa[axis] = so1
    sob = [so0]*d
    sob[axis] = so2
    p = [(0, 0)]*d
    p[axis] = (1, 1)
    imga = np.pad(img, p, mode='constant')
    return (imga[sob] - imga[soa])/(2.0*vox[axis])
```

timeit test and results (`vcalc` implements (1) and `vcalc_up` implements (2); `gradient` just calls `partial` along each image dimension):

```
import timeit
setup = """
import numpy as np
import vcalc
import vcalc_up

# Build zero padded 3d image similar to real MRI input
d = 3
so = [slice(20, -20, None)]*d
tmp = np.zeros((220,)*d)
tmp[so] = np.random.random((180,)*d)
vox = [1e-1]*d
"""

r = 5
i = 100
stmt = "vcalc.gradient(tmp, vox)"
tl = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup).repeat(r, i)
print tl
stmt = "vcalc_up.gradient(tmp, vox)"
tl = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup).repeat(r, i)
print tl
```

Output:

```
[60.21655583381653, 59.78620195388794, 60.69061803817749, 59.873075008392334, 60.28675389289856]
[84.67993712425232, 83.95580792427063, 84.6122419834137, 84.67212200164795, 84.78972506523132]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/05dc7b8b0662c9c973203b36044458ca35084833/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L693-L694) does convolution in the spatial domain rather than in the Fourier domain. There's a lot of indirection, but I think the C function that eventually gets called in your example is [`CASE_CORRELATE_POINT`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/05dc7b8b0662c9c973203b36044458ca35084833/scipy/ndimage/src/ni_filters.c#L141-L154) in `ni_filters.c`. There is also `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` if you want to try convolution in the Fourier domain.

Comment: But in that case, it's even more bizarre that the array slicing version is slower right? (Thank you for the edits, I'm relatively new to SO).

Comment: For one thing calling a single function compiled in C involves much less overhead than looping and slicing in Python, even if computing the diffs themselves is vectorized. Plus, I don't think it involves allocating as many arrays to store the intermediate results. I'm not sure if that's the whole story, but I think I would be more surprised if you *could* beat `ndimage.convolve` using pure numpy.

Comment: Using tools like numpy and scipy, it's sometimes difficult to know when the runtime is "implementation dominant" or "big O" dominant so to speak (I mean that with respect to the abstract problem, convolution vs. DFT vs. arithmetic in this case).

The "behind the scenes loops and allocations" explanation seems likely, but I'm hoping to catch a numpy or scipy developer to confirm it.

Comment: Well, you could always look at how your solution runtimes scale according to the array dimensions. For sufficiently large arrays then I would expect `fftconvolve` to eventually win out (provided that memory doesn't become the limiting factor).

Comment: I tried with `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. As it turns out, it is also slower than `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve` **for this particular convolution** (that is, first partial derivative along one direction for a 220x220x220 image). I think because the kernel is so small, the savings from the convolution theorem are less important than the time required to build equally sized arrays for the multiplication in the Fourier domain?